# How do I change the color of a Font Awesome icon when using <fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"> element

Tags: css, angular, frontend, font-awesome

How can I change the color of an Font Awesome icon using only css. This is how my code looks like

```
<div class="channel-type">
    <fa-icon [icon]="channel.getChannelType"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

And in my css

```
.channel-type fa-icon {
font-size: 30px;
line-height:30px;
color:black;
```

}

```
.channel-type fa-icon ?Here I need to indicate the specific icon (faFacebook) {
   color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply any class / id  with `<fa-icon>` element directly.

`<fa-icon class="iconColor" [icon]="channel.getChannelType"></fa-icon>`

`.iconColor{color:red }`

if specific like `faFacebook` this.

`<fa-icon class="icon-faFacebook" [icon]="channel.getChannelType"></fa-icon>`

use this with any prefix as a class name `icon-faFacebook`

`.icon-faFacebook{color:blue}`